# Left Join multiple table in sqlite

Tags: java, database, sqlite, left-join

How to join three tables in `SQLite`? I have three tables, one is `Info`, second is `workForce` and third is `workDetails`.

In order to join this three tables, I have added **foreign key of Table Info into Table WorkForce** and **foreign key of Table WorkForce into Table WorkDetails**

Table Info:`id(PK),name,status,date,weather`

Table WorkForce: `id1(PK), subContractors,noOfPeople,noOfHours,TInfo_id(FK to table Info)`

Table WorkDetails:`id2(PK),project,workDescription, Twf_id(FK to table workForce),TableInfo_id(FK to table Info) //contains multiple row`

**Table Info**

```
 ID          NAME        Weather        Date     Status
 ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
    1           Paul        Sunny         15/10      MC
    2           Allen       Rainy         15/10      Working
```

**Table WorkForce**

```
ID1          SubContractors   NoOfPeople      NoOfHours        TInfo_id
----------  --------------   ----------       ----------     -----------
1           AAA                2                 2                 1
2           BBB                3                 1                 2
```

**Table WorkDetails**

```
ID2         Project       WorkDescription        TableInfo_id      Twf_id
----------  ----------     --------------          ----------    ----------
1              A               B                       1             1
2                                                      1             1
3                                                      1             1
4                                                      1             1
5               C               D                      2             2
6                                                      2             2
7                                                      2             2
8                                                      2             2
```

Assume the name is Paul, so all the row with ID 1 and TableInfo_id 1 will be retrieved.

AND now, I want to retrieve them out into tableView by using `cursor`. Below are my code snippet.

**MyDatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="131.db";
    public static final String TABLE_INFO="Information";
    public static final String TABLE_WORKFORCE="WorkForce";
    public static final  String TABLE_WORKDETAILS="WorkDetails";
    public static final String Subcontractors="subcontractors";
    public static final String NumberOfPerson="numberOfPerson";
    public static final String NumberOfHours="numberOfHours";
    public static final String ID="id";
    public static final String ID1="id1";
    public static final String ID2="id2";
    public static final String Name="name";
    public static final String Weather="weather";
    public static final String Date="date";
    public static final String Project="project";
    public static final String WorkDescription="workDescription";
    public static final String Status="status";
    public static final String TableInfo_id="tableInfo_id";
    public static final String TInfo_id="tInfo_id";
    public static final String Twf_id="tWf_id";



    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_INFO + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT,Weather TEXT, Date DATETIME, Status Text)");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_WORKFORCE + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  ,Subcontractors TEXT,NumberOfPerson INTEGER,NumberOfHours TEXT,TInfo_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(TInfo_id) REFERENCES "+TABLE_INFO+"(ID))");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_WORKDETAILS + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , Project TEXT, WorkDescription TEXT,TableInfo_id INTEGER, Twf_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Twf_id) REFERENCES "+TABLE_WORKFORCE+"(ID), FOREIGN KEY(TableInfo_id) REFERENCES "+TABLE_INFO+"(ID))");
    }
```

**DisplayData.java**

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.displaydata);
            MyDatabaseHelper db = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
            InfoAPI I1 = new InfoAPI(this);
            sqlcon = new InfoAPI(this);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
            final String name1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"); //the name were pass from another activity
              BuildTable(name1);

        }


        private void BuildTable(String name)
        {

            sqlcon.open();
            Cursor c = sqlcon.readEntry(name);

            int rows = c.getCount();
            int cols = c.getColumnCount();

            c.moveToFirst();

            // outer for loop
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                row.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                // inner for loop
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    ));
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tv.setTextSize(18);
                    tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                    tv.setText(c.getString(j));

                    row.addView(tv);

                }

                c.moveToNext();

                table_layout.addView(row);

            }
            sqlcon.close();
        }

            }

**InfoAPI.java**

        public Cursor readEntry(String name) {

      //  String selectQuery = ("SELECT Weather,Date,Status,SubContractors,NumberOfPeople,NumberOfHours,TimeIn,TimeOut FROM "+
        //       MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO+MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_WORKFORCE+MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_WORKDETAILS+ "WHERE Name= ? AND"+MyDatabaseHelper.ID=MyDatabaseHelper.ID1+ "AND"+MyDatabaseHelper.ID=MyDatabaseHelper.TableInfo_id);
       return database.rawQuery("SELECT Information.weather, Information.date,Information.status"+"WorkForce.subContractors," +
               "WorkForce.noOfPeople,WorkForce.noOfHours"+"WorkDetails.project,WorkDetails.workDescription"+"FROM Information LEFT JOIN WorkForce" +
               " ON WorkForce.TInfo_id=Information.ID LEFT JOIN WorkDetails ON WorkDetails.Twf_id=WorkForce.ID1 WHERE Information.Name =?");

      //  if (c != null) {
        //    c.moveToFirst();
       // }
       // return c;

    }
}
```

The compiler give me **cannot resolve rawQuery error**.  I've been searching the answer for quite a long time but still cannot fix it. Not sure whether the error is came from query problem or not. Any suggestion would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: You are mussing some commas and spaces in your query. Check it again. Look at the parts where you concatenate strings in your query

Comment: how about the name? The name was passing from previous activity to InfoAPI. How should I put it into query?

Comment: If your question is how to do multiple joins in sqlite, than you don't  need to give us all the java code.

Comment: I didn't gave you all java code..I only post some relevance code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     public Cursor readEntry(String name) {

           return database.rawQuery("SELECT i.Weather, i.Date, i.Status, w.SubContractors, w.NumberOfPerson, w.NumberOfHours, 
wd.Project, wd.WorkDescription FROM Information i LEFT JOIN WorkForce w 
ON w.TInfo_id = i.ID LEFT JOIN WorkDetails wd ON wd.Twf_id = w.ID WHERE
 i.Name = ?",new String[] {String.valueOf(name)},null);

        }
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the query more readable using table aliases:

```
SELECT i.weather, i.date, i.status, w.subContractors, w.noOfPeople, w.noOfHours, 
       wd.project, wd.workDescription
FROM Information i LEFT JOIN
     WorkForce w 
     ON w.TInfo_id = i.ID LEFT JOIN
     WorkDetails wd
     ON wd.Twf_id = WorkForce.ID1
WHERE i.Name = ?
```

However, the cause of your problem is that when the strings combine, values are running together, such as "WorkDetails.workDescription"+"FROM " --> "WorkDetails.workDescriptionFROM ".

You would easily see this problem if you printed out the query after constructing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But how about the name which was passing from previous activity to InfoAPI. How should I put it into query?